# Making Mac/Linux binary out of mono/C#

Tags: mono, binary

Compiling C# code in Mac gives me a binary that runs on mono. I need to run 'mono abc.exe' to run the binary.

- Can I make a binary that doesn't need mono to run with mono/C#?

If so, how good is the result? If not, is there a way to run the binary not with 'mono abc.exe' but with 'abc.exe'?

### ADDED

I needed some more effort in order to run mkbundle with mono 2.10.2 on Snow Leopard - [An issue when running mono 2.10.2 mkbundle on Mac OS X snow leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442223/an-issue-when-running-mono-2-10-2-mkbundle-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/6444606#6444606)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options: mkbundle and a shell wrapper. Use first if you're not expecting to find mono on all the boxes you're going to run your executable file, and the second option otherwise.