# An issue when running mono 2.10.2 mkbundle on Mac OS X snow leopard

Tags: .net, macos, mono, mkbundle

[This page](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime) has info about Bundles with `mkbundle`, but when I tried to use it on Mac, I got this error message.

```
delegate> mkbundle delegate.exe -o delegate
OS is: Darwin
Sources: 1 Auto-dependencies: False
   embedding: /Users/smcho/Desktop/csharp/delegate/delegate.exe
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s 
temp.s:2:unknown section type: symbol_stubs
temp.s:2:Rest of line ignored. 1st junk character valued 112 (p).
[Fail]
```

And from [this site](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td1549372), I could run `export AS="as -arch i386"` to get another error.

```
Compiling:
as -arch i386 -o temp.o temp.s 
cc -g -o a.out -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`  temp.o
ld: warning: ignoring file /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.2/lib/libmono-2.0.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: ignoring file temp.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_mono_register_bundled_assemblies", referenced from:
      _mono_mkbundle_init in cczw6Dmo.o
  "_mono_set_dirs", referenced from:
      _main in cczw6Dmo.o
  "_mono_main", referenced from:
      _main in cczw6Dmo.o
  "_assembly_data_ser_exe", referenced from:
      _assembly_bundle_ser_exe in cczw6Dmo.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
[Fail]
```

I see this is a problem of 32bit/64bit compilation issue, then how to remove this error message? I tried with `export CC="cc -arch i386"`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had to take the following steps.

1. export AS="as -arch i386"
2. export CC="cc -arch i386"
3. Run without `--static` option. Just run `mkbuild BINARY`. With the option --deps, it seems to embed more dlls. You can use -z option to zip the embedded libraries.

You may get more hints from [this](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td3224539), and  [this](http://cobra-language.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&p=3745#p3745). Mono's mkbundle is explained in [this](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications).

Comment: This worked for me -- do you know what "AS" and "CC" means and why this fix worked?