# mkbundle on Mac with Mono: "mono/metadata/mono-config.h" file not found

Tags: c#, macos, mono, mkbundle

I'm trying to create a Mac bundle with Mono. When I execute:

```
    mkbundle file.exe --deps -o FILE
```

I get this during compilation:

```
    fatal error: "mono/metadata/mono-config.h" file not found
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8):

The key is the preceding error (`sh: pkg-config: command not found`),
note that pkg-config is stored at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands'.

Solution (see [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/devel@lists.monobjc.net/msg00018.html) and [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=513662)):

Prepend the "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands" folder to
your PATH variable:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:$PATH
```

In addition (as proposed by aiapatag and the [objective-c runtime and CoreFoundation framework solution proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089844/mono-3-4-0-mkbundle-under-mac-os-x-failed)).

```
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="cc -arch i386 -framework CoreFoundation -lobjc -liconv"
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this same problem on my Mac.  I solved it by setting pkg-config.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.0.12/lib/pkgconfig
```

Just a heads up, for Mac you have to...

```
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="cc -arch i386"
```

...as stated here [An issue when running mono 2.10.2 mkbundle on Mac OS X snow leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442223/an-issue-when-running-mono-2-10-2-mkbundle-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard) but on Mountain Lion, I had to do this instead so that the app could run on Lion.

```
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="clang -arch i386 -mmacosx-version-min=10.6"
```

Comment: You just saved my day. For many, changing ```3.0.12``` by ```Current``` may just work.

Answer (score 4):

Try reinstalling Mono Development Kit (MDK). Do not install Mono Runtime Environment (MRE) on top of MDK. MDK will suffice.

Then, if you're using Windows (but I guess you're on OSX -- but just to mention): you will need a Unix-like toolchain for mkbundle to to work.

*Excerpt: from [their site](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkbundle)*

> On Windows systems, it it necessary to have Unix-like toolchain to be
>   installed for mkbundle to work. You can use cygwin's and install gcc,
>   gcc-mingw and as packages. (sic)