# Mono mkbundle on OSX

Tags: macos, mono, mkbundle

I'm trying to create a standalone of my C# app using mono's mkbundle, I got Xcode installed and the Mono Developer Kit too (I'm sure it's MDK not the runtime). Yet I run mkbundle using
mkbundle test.exe

and I get these errors

```
Compiling:
as -o temp.o temp.s 
cc -g -o a.out -Wall temp.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2`  temp.o
sh: pkg-config: command not found
temp.c:1:10: fatal error: 'mono/metadata/mono-config.h' file not found

1 error generated.
[Fail]
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 3):

pkg-config is stored at '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands'.

Solution (see [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/devel@lists.monobjc.net/msg00018.html) and [here](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=513662)):

Prepend the "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands" folder to
your PATH variable:

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands:$PATH
```

This is needed in addition to the [architecture solution proposed by aiapatag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979044/mkbundle-on-mac-with-mono-mono-metadata-mono-config-h-file-not-found/27075282) and the [objective-c runtime and CoreFoundation framework solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089844/mono-3-4-0-mkbundle-under-mac-os-x-failed):

```
export AS="as -arch i386"
export CC="cc -arch i386 -framework CoreFoundation -lobjc -liconv"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the pkg-config tool is not found. Maybe it's not in the default paths.

Do you have a 'pkgconfig' directory somewhere? It should be a subdirectory of your Mono installation.
Try to see if you have a path looking like  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/XXXX/lib/pkgconfig

If yes, point the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to this path, you can specify it directly when running your mkbundle command (this is just an example):

```
$ PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/XXXX/lib/pkgconfig mkbundle ....
```